# How do I turn on/off "Student can see class summary" in callng "Classroom.Courses.courseWork.create()" of GAS?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-classroom

I am coding a script to create MULTIPLE_CHOICE_QUESTION of google-classroom-coursework.
I have written most of it, but cannot find how to turn on/off the flag of *"Student can see class summary"*.
How do I do it ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to do the exact same thing before but I am afraid that this is a feature that is not available in the Google Classroom API yet.

You can submit this as a feature request using the [URL](https://developers.google.com/classroom/support#missing_features) below.